# In Evernote, "state" parameter in authorization url is not getting passed in callback

Tags: evernote

I'm using scribe for oauth. In authorization url, I'm passing 'state' parameter with a token to identify the user during callback request.

authorizationUrl = EVERNOTE_SERVICE.getAuthorizationUrl(requestTokenObject.getToken());
log.info("Auth url : " + authorizationUrl);
redirect(authorizationUrl + "&state=" + token);

But in the callback, I'm not receiving the "state" parameter. I'm only receiving "oauth_token" and "oauth_verifier" in the callback. I'm expecting this has to work and everyone else should be doing this already. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evernote currently uses OAuth1.0, it looks like the `state` parameter was added in OAuth2. OAuth1.0 does not have a state parameter.

Comment: Thanks. But then what are the options to trace a call back request to a certain user?

Comment: You'll have to do some session management on your end - in example apps we've written, we utilize and http session and store things in there.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the a state parameter back in the callback, by adding it to the callback url as query parameter.

The url for `oauth_callback` looks something like this then: `http://localhost?state={state}`